# Summation transformation formula(s)

Tags: summation

According to this [link](http://nbl.cewit.stonybrook.edu:60128/mediawiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.3)
$$
\sum\limits_{k=j}^{i+j} (j+i-k)
$$
is
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^i (k)
$$
Can someone write the Sum formula(s) which was used in this transformation?

Comment: Hint: how many sum terms are in the first sum?  What values do the terms take on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing it, 
\begin{align*}
 &\;\;\; \sum\limits_{k=j}^{i+j} (j+i-k) \\ 
 &= ((j + i - j) + (j + i - j - 1) + \dots + 1 + 0)\\
 &= (i + (i-1) + ... +  1) \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^i k
\end{align*}

Shifting index $k \to k + j$,
$$\sum\limits_{k=j}^{i+j} (j+i-k)= \sum_{k=0}^i (j + i - (k+j)) = \sum_{k=0}^i (i-k) = \sum_{k=1}^i k$$

Comment: Almost there but I don't understand according which rule you have transformed
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^i (i-k)
$$
to
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^i (k)
$$

Comment: @pierre either you count it from back or front, it's just same. the sum is like that. it is just adding the sum from back instead of front.

Comment: @pierre or just try this 
$$\sum_{k=1}^i i - \sum_{k=1}^i k = i(i+1) - \frac{i(i+1)}{2} = \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, one more think, why
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^i i = i(i + 1)
$$

I think **i** in this case is constant and according to next rule:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^i c = ci
$$

it should be **i^2**

Comment: @pierre yes you are absolutely correct ... but my index begins from 0.
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^i c = c(i+1)$
Woops!! sorry ... my mistake. on earlier sum ... the index begins from zero.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do things a bit differently; maybe that will make it clearer.

All that happened here is *re-indexing* of the terms of the sequence.  In other words, all of the same terms appear... we're just assigning them a different index number, and possibly re-ordering them.

You started off here with
$$
\sum_{k=j}^{i+j}(j+i-k).
$$
Notice that $j+i$ never changes.  Let's define a new index of summation, say $t$, by $t=j+i-k$.

Notice that when we plug in $k=j$, we get $t=i$; when we plug in $k=j+1$, we get $t=i-1$; and so on, and so forth, until we get to $k=j+i$, in which case $t=0$.

So, summing over all values of $k$ between $j$ and $j+i$ is the same as summing over all values of $t$ between $0$ and $i$. All that remains is to rewrite our index $k$ term of the summand in terms of $t$; since $t=j+i-k$, this term is precisely $t$. So, we conclude that
$$
\sum_{k=j}^{j+i}(j+i-k)=\sum_{t=0}^{i}t.
$$

Does that help?

Comment: Ok, but in this link which I posted is that transformed sum start from **1** and you have **t=0**.

Comment: @pierre Okay.  That's true.  But we have
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{i}t=\underbrace{0}_{t=0}+\sum_{t=1}^{i}t=\sum_{t=1}^{i}t,
$$
which takes care of it.

Comment: You are right too. Thanks.